# Azure functions Blob Storage Date Time output path

Tags: function, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-functions

I have an azure function with Blob Storage as an output.
My question is how to specify a **{date}/{time}** output path pattern from the Azure functions? I don't want to store all blobs flat in the container.

I tried **mycontainername/{date}/{time}**, but it complaints saying "No binding parameter exists for 'date'"

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `datetime` parameter resolver with the appropriate format string.

For example:

`{datetime:yyyy}` will result in 2017 (on 2017)

`{datetime:hhmmss}` will result in hours, minutes and seconds, with no separators.

The format strings used are the ones supported by the .NET framework and you can learn more about them [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx). (Standard strings are also supported).

Comment: I tried **mycontainername/{datetime:yyyy}** but got an exception
**Expecting element 'base64Binary' from namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/'.. Encountered 'Element'  with name 'string', namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/'.**
My azure function input is Service Bus Topic.

Comment: That sounds unrelated to the named input. Can you share more details (logs/response) on the error you're seeing?

Comment: Actually, that was the only error I sent already, agree that no relation to the name..
I ended up with using BlobAttribute and Binder, more details are [here](http://blog.xebia.com/azure-functions-imperative-bindings/)
So, my path is **"string path = $"mycontainer/{DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd/HH")}" + name;"**
Thanks, your answer helped me to find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it now in **Java Azure Function** as well.

**{DateTime}**

example:

```
@BlobOutput(name = "blob", connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage", path = "samples-java/new-{DateTime}.zip") OutputBinding<byte[]> blob
```